# Loading a new DataContext from deserialized JSON

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I have a class as my datacontext, it will be extended later on :

```
public class CMiX_Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public class VidFlip : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _VidFlipX;
        public bool VidFlipX
        {
            get { return _VidFlipX; }
            set{ if (value != _VidFlipX)
                {
                    { _VidFlipX = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled"); }
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("property"+propertyName+"changed");
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<VidFlip> _Collection = new ObservableCollection<VidFlip>(new[] { new VidFlip { VidFlipX = true }, new VidFlip { VidFlipX = false }, new VidFlip { VidFlipX = false }, new VidFlip { VidFlipX = false }, new VidFlip { VidFlipX = false }, new VidFlip { VidFlipX = false } }  );
    public ObservableCollection<VidFlip> Collection
    {
        get { return _Collection; }
        set { _Collection = value; OnPropertyChanged("Collection"); }
    }
}
```

I save and load JSON file this way :

```
public partial class CMiX_UI : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged, ISupportsUndo
{
    private event EventHandler OnSelect;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    CMiX_UserControl.Properties.Settings();

    CMiX_Data data = new CMiX_Data();

    public CMiX_UI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new CMiX_Data();
    }

    private void MenuSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
        serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Google Drive\PROJECT\_C-MiX\_C-MiX-2.0\pouet.txt"))
        using(JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("saved");
    }

    private void MenuLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (var re = File.OpenText(@"D:\Google Drive\PROJECT\_C-MiX\_C-MiX-2.0\pouet.txt"))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(re))
        {
            CMiX_Data entries = serializer.Deserialize<CMiX_Data>(reader);
            DataContext = entries;
            MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
        }
    }
```

And the saved data in JSON (here the observablecollection) look like this :

```
{"Collection":[{"VidFlipX":true},{"VidFlipX":false},{"VidFlipX":false},{"VidFlipX":false},{"VidFlipX":false},{"VidFlipX":false}]}
```

What is saved is what I've got on the UI. But when loading the JSON file, the datacontext or the observablecollection always goes back to its original states (the one shows above) instead of being modified by what has been loaded...

Any idea ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your public CMiX_UI class you are creating two separate instances of CMiX_Data class, one during the initialization "CMiX_Data data = new CMiX_Data();" and one in constructure "this.DataContext = new CMiX_Data();". I think in the constructure you should be using the previously created object as follows: this.DataContext = this.data;.